# C#: Comparing xml schema files

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, diff

I've been tasked to compare two XML schema files in C# and present differences between the two in an output XML document. I've researched the subject a bit to find a tool that could help me do this, but so far I've come up pretty dry.

There's a dead microsoft project on the subject that actually works pretty well called [XML Diff and Patch GUI Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302295.aspx#xmldif_topic3) which I'll probably end up using...but this project is six years old, subject to terrible linkrot and limited documentation and so can't possibly be the best solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I was actually going to suggest the MS Diff and patch tool - the actual API isn't too bad - I mostly use it in some unit tests which verify an XML document is generated correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to compare schemas; an older version of the idea is comparing DTDs.

You might find this answer useful:
[How can I determine if a given DTD a subset of another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370073/looking-for-a-dtd-diff-tool-is-a-given-dtd-a-subset-of-another)

While that answer focuses on DTDs, the tool behind it isn't fussy and is happy to compare any XML structures including Schemas.